# Is it safe to remove an entry in a "config.mongos" MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

There are old entries in my "config.mongos"; they reference hosts which previously had "mongos" running on them but no longer do.

Can I safely remove those entries?

```
e.g.,:
# Old entries
{ "_id" : "silicon:27117", "ping" : ISODate("2012-12-27T19:51:04.560Z"), "up" : 9301, "waiting" : true }
...
# Current entries
{ "_id" : "app1:27017", "ping" : ISODate("2013-06-07T17:12:02.856Z"), "up" : 5593404, "waiting" : true }
{ "_id" : "app2:27017", "ping" : ISODate("2013-06-07T16:17:49.812Z"), "up" : 5590271, "waiting" : false }
{ "_id" : "app4:27017", "ping" : ISODate("2013-06-07T17:12:02.110Z"), "up" : 5593413, "waiting" : true }
{ "_id" : "app3:27017", "ping" : ISODate("2013-06-07T17:12:02.854Z"), "up" : 5593578, "waiting" : true }
```

**Update:**

One reason why having these old entries in `config.mongos` is a problem is that making changes to the shard takes a long time, while we wait for old `mongos`es to time out.

For example, stopping the balancer takes a long time (several minutes):

```
mongos> sh.stopBalancer()
Waiting for active hosts...
Waiting for active host magnesium:27117 to recognize new settings... (ping : Thu Dec 22 2011 03:08:14 GMT+0000 (UTC))
Waited for active ping to change for host magnesium:27117, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Waiting for active host Boron:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Tue Jan 31 2012 21:48:12 GMT+0000 (UTC))
Waited for active ping to change for host Boron:27017, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Waiting for active host Beryllium:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Wed Feb 01 2012 17:34:15 GMT+0000 (UTC))
Waited for active ping to change for host Beryllium:27017, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Waiting for active host helium:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Mon Jun 10 2013 19:07:41 GMT+0000 (UTC))
Waited for active ping to change for host helium:27017, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Waiting for active host boron:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Sun Jun 02 2013 08:46:57 GMT+0000 (UTC))
Waited for active ping to change for host boron:27017, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Waiting for the balancer lock...
```

Comment: the timeout is not based on the number of mongos entries in that collection, it's strictly a time based timeout (60 seconds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove these entries, but there is really no reason to do so.  The `config.mongos` collection just records all `mongos` processes that have connected to the config server in question.  Hence any that reconnect at any point will just show up again - it's a book keeping thing, and only takes up a few KB at most, there's no need to delete them.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the old entries. In my experience it does take longer to perform `sh.stopBalancer()` if there is an old entry that is still treated as an active host.

Example:

```
Waiting for active hosts...
Waiting for active host oldnode.domain.com:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Tue Aug 20 2013 21:16:24 GMT+0000 (UTC))
Waited for active ping to change for host oldnode.domain.com:27017, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Waiting for active host freshnode.domain.com:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Wed Jun 20 2018 05:34:09 GMT+0000 (UTC))
Waiting for the balancer lock...
Waiting again for active hosts after balancer is off...
Waiting for active host oldnode.domain.com:27017 to recognize new settings... (ping : Tue Aug 20 2013 21:16:24 GMT+0000 (UTC))
Waited for active ping to change for host oldnode.domain.com:27017, a migration may be in progress or the host may be down.
Warning : host oldnode.domain.com:27017 seems to have been offline since Tue Aug 20 2013 21:16:24 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

To remove an old entry:

1. Connect to mongos using `mongo`.
2. `use config`
3. `db.mongos.remove({"_id": "oldnode.domain.com:port"})`